# No sound,Ubuntu server12.04

Tags: 12.04, command-line, server

I have installed ubuntu server 12.04 on my computer. Today when I was trying to listening music,I found there was no sound. The player I used is mplayer. May be I didn't install sound driver but I don't how to do that in the command line environment.

I have installed alsamixer and turned all volumes to the top, but theres is still no sound.

[alsa-info.sh results](http://pastebin.mozilla.org/3912160)

Comment: Some output from your alsa would help, [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo). Is pulseaudio installed?

Comment: I have not installed pulseaudio.  Is that the solution?    I have installed pulseaudio just now :"sudo apt-get install pulseaudio",But it's still no sound

Comment: No, I'm just asking that to know what is your sound setup. (To know if it is a problem in pulse or in ALSA?) I don't think pulse is necessary for your server.

Comment: It's seems that there is no alsamixer in my computer

Comment: I have installed alsamixer and turn all volumes to the top, but it still no sound

Comment: http://pastebin.mozilla.org/3912160   finally,I upload it successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `alsa-info` output says that the Master volume meter is muted (**[off]**):

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [off]
```

You have to unmute it in `alsamixer` by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> while that meter is selected.